# Is there a way to get the return value of an async js generator function without a while loop

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an async generator function that I would like to just get the return value for without calling next a bunch of times. Right now I have something like this:

```
async function *getData(): AsyncGenerator<object[], object[]>
{
    let results = []
    let res = {};

    while (true)
    {
        res = await apiCall(res.next);
        results.push(...res.data)
        if (!res.next) break;
        yield res.data;
    }
    return results;
}

async function main()
{
    const genFn = getData();
    while (!(await genFn.next()).done) {}
}
```

Is there a better/more concise way that doesn't need the while loop?

Comment: ?? This doesn't make sense. Why use a generator at all if you don't want to iterate (in some way) through the yielded values?

Comment: Because sometimes I want to iterate and sometimes I just want the result, and I don't want to have duplicate functions that do the same thing. I updated the example to better fit with what I'm doing. Hopefully the why makes more sense now

Comment: Well a function is either a generator with one or more `yield` points, or it isn't. You can't have a single function behave both ways. You could, however, write another function whose sole purpose is to iterate through a generator until it flags `done`.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can do besides creating a function that does it for you to clean things up. You can use a `for-await` instead of a while loop though.

```js
async function drainAsyncIterable(iterable) {
  const iterator = iterable[Symbol.asyncIterator]();
  while (!(await iterator.next()).done) {}
}
```

vs

```js
async function drainAsyncIterable(iterable) {
  for await (const _ of iterable) {}
}
```

Comment: Recently found out that the for await loop does not acquire the `return` value. To actually get that value, you need to use a while loop or just manually call `next()`.